# Windows 8.1 logging me out immediately?

Tags: windows-8

So, I recently upgraded to windows 8.1, and now I have this problem that whenever I log into my main admin acct. It logs me out immediately... I maybe have 2 seconds at best. Before windows 8.1 this happened too, except I was able to CRTL+ALT+DEL and go into task manager and that would stop it, but now I don't have any time... Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: This only happens to admin accounts... The rest of the family works fine.

EDIT 2: Even the default admin account doesn't work...

EDIT 3: Getting "The server {AB8902B4-09CA-4BB6-B78D-A8F59079A8D5} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout." Error in event viewer under the account that's not working

EDIT 4: Scanning right now for corrupt files w/ sfc /scannow ... We'll see how it goes.

EDIT 5: No issues?!?! I don't think so...

EDIT 6: Works in safe mode... How do I identify what program/service/virus is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging into the admin account in safe mode and check if some third party application is messing with your log on.

Here's how you can boot into [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode).

Once the problem is solved in safe boot you have to perform a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135). After the clean boot you have to open up task manager by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Esc` then switching to **Start-up** tab. Under the tab enable the applications (which are in disabled state) one by one [2 or 3 at once to save time] till you find the culprit.

Comment: Okay, will try once sfc /scannow is done

Comment: okay, it worked in safe mode. How do I Identify what program/service/virus is causing this?

Comment: Okay perform a clean boot or disable the apps that you have recently installed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Comment: okay, I did. It still attempted to sign me out, but another program that wasn't starting let me cancel it cause of the "This program is preventing you from signing out" bu, it's still not working...

Comment: You just have to keep filtering the applications until you find the culprit or perform a clean boot and enable the applications one by one [2 or 3 at once to save time] till you find the culprit. That's all you can do since the safe boot worked for you.

Comment: Okay, so I guess what you're saying is go into safe mode, and start the programs in the startup thingy in msgconfig one by one?

Comment: No, safe mode will not allow you to start the applications. Check my second comment. It performs a clean boot. Then you can enable the applications one by one.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!!! It was a screensaver that was actually a virus that caused it :P

Comment: Hi, I request you to update this question with the resoution and if my answered helped you please mark it as answer.